# You don't seem to have 'make' or 'gmake' in your PATH - MinGW32 (windows)

Tags: windows, qt, raspberry-pi, mingw, raspberry-pi2

I recently started a project on my new Pi2 and Qt. A few hours ago I started to prepare the cross-compiler following [this](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/) tutorial, but when It came the moment of running the configuration script it told me:

> $ ../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/configure -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opengl
>    es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -sysroot C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5
>   + cd qtbase
>   + /c/Users/Carlos Xammar/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/configure -top-level -platform win32-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -sysroot C:/SysGCC/Raspberry/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5
>   dirname: extra operand `Xammar/Desktop/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/configure'
>   Try`dirname --help' for more information.
>   You don't seem to have 'make' or 'gmake' in your PATH.
>   Cannot proceed.

I made all the steps ok but I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to export MAKE environment variable, like this: `export MAKE="mingw32-make"`